# script causes links to have a timed delay

Tags: jquery, css

This little piece of jquery results in something funny happening to all other links on the page, namely, they do whatever they're supposed to do BUT only after an odd time delay of about 1 second.

This happens after clicking a link that runs the following code:

```
$('#content').on("click", "a#goto_faq", function() {

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1234, 'easeInExpo');

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';  

    $('#content').delay(888).slideUp(888,'easeOutExpo',loadContent);        
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);  
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').slideDown(777,'easeInExpo');
    }
    $("html, body").delay(777).animate({ scrollTop: 405 }, 777, 'easeInExpo',goToFAQ);
    function goToFAQ() {
    $("html, body").delay(2700).animate({ scrollTop: 1415 }, 2222, 'easeInOutExpo');
    }
    return false;

});
```

So you click on a id="goto_faq", and everything loads and scrolls the window just fine. Once all the functions/anim's complete, whichever link you decide to click on next is going to take about one second before it fires off. (All links are fine from then on -- it's just the first one after the above script. [It makes one think the script must still be running in the background.])

I've been playing around with jquery.stop for some time now, but so far no luck. I seem to be unable to understand jquery from reading the API Docs. Any help with .stop would be appreciated; thanks.

Comment: That code should only work on one single element, as it uses an ID, and ID's are unique ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using delegation. Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Look for the example on delegating. That may help you.

Comment: Sorry, should have read further that the docs are not really helping you that much, and here I go linking a doc...

Comment: If I were running this place, I would strongly advise against all those "look at the docs" types of replies (and this place is littered with them), as it is often a way of telling someone they're lazy/stoopid or just not cool enough to hang with the advanced stackoverflow nerds. If I'm here: yeah, I googled it, yeah I read the docs, and yeah, I messed around with the same piece of code for a few hours. I'm just not a left-brained guy -- that's why I come here, to consult with you left-brain folks. The difficulty is the left brain is paranoid about the right brain.